# Littlewood-Richardson rule for the complete flag variety: GapP complete?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, co.combinatorics, computational-complexity, schubert-calculus

The cohomology ring of a complete flag variety $X$ has a basis of Schubert classes $S_u$ for permutations $u$. Define the Littlewood-Richardson coefficient $c_{uv}^w$ for permutations $u,v,w$ to be the coefficient of $S_w$ in the expansion of $S_uS_v$ in terms of the basis. The problem is to compute $c_{uv}^w$ given $u,v,w$.

I (and others) have found some formulas for Littlewood-Richardson coefficients in the complete flag variety that show that the problem is in GapP, meaning it is the difference of two #P problems. Despite decades of effort, no one has yet found a formula that shows the problem is in #P (i.e. a Littlewood-Richardson rule). I've tried on and off for 9 years myself.

This would make sense if the problem were complete for the complexity class GapP; it is widely believed that $\mathrm{GapP}^+\neq\#\mathrm P$, where $\mathrm{GapP}^+$ is the set of GapP problems where the result is positive, which would imply that no Littlewood-Richardson rule exists. Is it known whether the problem is GapP-complete?

Comment: Don't you want to explain, what is the problem?

Comment: @Sasha added an explicit statement of the problem.

Comment: Is it about complete flags in type A, or in arbitrary Dynkin type?

Comment: @Sasha my GapP formula works for all types, including infinite-dimensional Kac-Moody, so it doesn't matter, but I would guess even in type A alone it would be complete for the complexity class.

Comment: Isn't this question essentially asking about the status of a well-known open problem?

Comment: @Sam well I'm not asking if anyone has found a Littlewood-Richardson rule, just whether it's known if the problem is GapP-complete. I've never seen a paper that considers this question, so if you know of some perhaps you could point me to them?

Comment: @MattSamuel: But as you point out, the problem being GapP-complete is morally equivalent to it being impossible to find a Littlewood-Richardson rule. So presumably it would be big news if someone could show it is GapP-complete.

Comment: @SamHopkins well it's been years I've been working on this and I only recently considered this possibility, even though I've known about GapP and had the formula for two thirds of that time. I'm not saying I'm the benchmark against which all research should be measured,  but it's conceivable that no one made the connection. I've seen a proof that something related is GapP complete.

Comment: @SamHopkins you're probably right anyway, so I think I'll start trying to prove it myself.